# HIVE and where and date statements

Tags: date, hive, where-clause, between

How do I fix this code to make it work in HIVE?  I tried multiple combinations of () but nothing works…

```
Where (DOB is not NULL) 
  and (DATE_FORMAT(DOB, 'yyyyMM') BETWEEN 201601 AND 201805) 
  and (color in ('orange', ‘blue', 'pink'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`(DOB is not NULL)` condition is redundant, because if `DATE_FORMAT(DOB, 'yyyyMM') BETWEEN 201601 AND 201805` then DOB is definitely NOT NULL.

So this should work (fix wrong single-quote near `blue`):

```
Where (DATE_FORMAT(DOB, 'yyyyMM') BETWEEN 201601 AND 201805) 
  and (color in ('orange', 'blue', 'pink'))
```

date_format works only if first argument is correct date or timestamp: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS`, if not, use something else to extract `yyyyMM`